# Need Difference between two dates in different ID's same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in sql server 2012 which has an ID, startDate and EndDate if the id's are 1,2,3 and 4 with respective dates, i would like to get difference between endDate of ID = 1 and startDate of ID=2 and so on i cannot seems to get an IDEA, anyhelp will be very good thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) window function:

```
select t.*
  , DaysUntilNextStartDate = datediff(day,t.enddate,lead(startdate) over (order by id))+1
from t
```

Using [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select t.*
  , DaysUntilNextStartDate = datediff(day,t.enddate,n.startdate)+1
from t
  outer apply (
    select top 1
        i.startdate
    from t as i
    where i.id > t.id
    order by i.id asc
    ) as n
```

Using a self join (if the `id` is always sequential, without gaps):

```
select t.*
  , DaysUntilNextStartDate = datediff(day,t.enddate,n.startdate)+1
from t
  left join t as n 
    on t.id+1 = n.id
```